# Select same pixels across all images and delete/make transparent them

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a bunch of images (they are in-game screenshots) that are "watermarked" with the GUI (there are controls, stats, etc.) and I want to select the pixels consistent accross all of them. I messed with it in Photoshop and managed to somehow separate the GUI by loading the images into stack and setting modes of all layers to "difference". There must be an easy solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Difference is one way to do it. After you isolate the pixels, flatten the image, select all, copy, then undo the flatten.

Make a new layer group, apply a layer mask to it, then switch to channels, activate the layer mask channel and paste the (copy from above) into the layer mask channel.

Move all your layers into the group and set them back to normal.

You can adjust contrast, invert the mask, and touch up as needed.

Comment: Yeah. That worked too. I originally did the layer mask the hard way. I saved that as selection, then restored that selection on every image and deleted. Is there any way to make photoshop do this more automatically?

Comment: I don't really know, but if you were to, say find a very dark corner or room in the game and then take a screencap, that might serve as a universal mask without much tweaking

Comment: Too bad there are no such corners. :( Anyway, I was making a reposition, I'll try it with these pictures and hope for the best...